# Can an uploaded File Body/Data be copied to a Document Object?

Tags: attachment, files

I am currently using Attachments (not Files) and we move the FeedItem data to our custom Document object.  Is there a way to capture the File upload and do the following, that is done with Attachments?  TIA

```
for(Attachment a : attachments) {
    FeedItem document = new FeedItem();
    document.ParentId = chatterGroupMap.get(documentChatterGroupMap.get('Some Group'));
    document.ContentData = a.Body;
    document.ContentDescription = a.Description;
    document.ContentFileName = a.Name;
    document.Type = 'ContentPost';
    document.Title = a.Name;
    insert document;  
}
```

Comment: What is this "custom" Document object that you referred to in OP?

Comment: Ignore that custom...  I just need to figure out how to do the above with Files and not attachments.

Comment: Files are `ContentVersion` -- and you can do triggers on `ContentVersion` - give it a try and come back to us if you get stuck.  Note that your code above is not bulkified - the insert needs to be from a collection and outside the for loop